# Split Data in chunks and upload to server

Tags: ios, alamofire

I have a file that needed to be uploaded to a server and I have been told to separate the file into multiple chunks before uploading. So here is the question:

1) I have converted the file into "Data" type (bytes). How do I split it into chunks of 1MB each?
2) After splitting, how do I upload it using Alamofire? if not possible using Alamofire, pls recommend how do I do it.

I'm using swift 3 and Code 8.3. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343053/how-to-work-with-large-file-uploads-in-ios and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833223/upload-large-file-video-to-server-in-ios

Answer (score 7):

I think this may work

```
let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "png")!
    
do
{
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)
    let dataLen = (data as NSData).length
    let fullChunks = Int(dataLen / 1024) // 1 Kbyte
    let totalChunks = fullChunks + (dataLen % 1024 != 0 ? 1 : 0)
        
    var chunks:[Data] = [Data]()
    for chunkCounter in 0..<totalChunks
    {
        var chunk:Data
        let chunkBase = chunkCounter * 1024
        var diff = 1024
        if chunkCounter == totalChunks - 1
        {
            diff = dataLen - chunkBase
        }
            
        let range:Range<Data.Index> = chunkBase..<(chunkBase + diff)
        chunk = data.subdata(in: range)
            
        chunks.append(chunk)
    }
        
    // Send chunks as you want
    debugPrint(chunks)
}
catch
{
    // Handle error        
}
```

Comment: this one working fine in split of _nsdata_ to chunks of _nsdata_

Comment: It will crash on this line `let data = try Data(contentsOf: path)` in case of large file. But this approach is ok for small files.